# XamGrid RowSelectorColumn does not expand for larger row numbers

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics

As the title states the XamGrid control's RowSelectorColumn does not expand for larger numbers.

[image: Example of squeezed row numbers]

As you can see it is a very tight fit.

I can set the width explicitly, but theoretically a user could add enough rows that I will end up with the same problem again.

I've also tried:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igPrim:RowSelectorColumn}" >
     <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
</Style>
```

Is there a way to get the RowSelectorColumn (or CellControl) width to expand when the contents start to get large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how add some padding to the row numbers. You need to redefine the the `DataTemplate` and set the `Padding` property that way. I tried to set the `Padding` directly on the `RowSelectorCellControl` but saw no results, so you have to do it through a data template. This [article](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/blagunas/archive/2012/07/16/xamgrid-data-bind-checkbox-in-row-selector.aspx) helped me figure out what I needed to do.

```
            <ig:XamGrid.RowSelectorSettings>
                <ig:RowSelectorSettings Visibility="Visible" EnableRowNumbering="True">
                    <ig:RowSelectorSettings.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igPrim:RowSelectorCellControl}">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cell.Row.Index, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type igPrim:RowSelectorCellControl}}}"
                                                   Padding="3,0,3,0"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                            Value="{Binding ElementName=ContainingGrid, Path=DataContext.GridFontSize}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ig:RowSelectorSettings.Style>
                </ig:RowSelectorSettings>
            </ig:XamGrid.RowSelectorSettings>
```